# How to get the top position of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get the top position of an element using javascript/jquery ?

The element is a table, if that matters.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

If you want the position relative to the document then:

```
$("#myTable").offset().top;
```

but often you will want the position relative to the closest positioned parent:

```
$("#myTable").position().top;
```

Answer (score 13):

```
$("#myTable").offset().top;
```

This will give you the computed offset (relative to document) of any object.

Answer (score 8):

```
var top = event.target.offsetTop + 'px';
```

Parent element top position like we are adding elemnt inside div

```
var rect = event.target.offsetParent;
         rect.offsetTop;
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>position demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  p {
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<p></p>
 
<script>
var p = $( "p" ).first();
var position = p.position();
$( "p" ).last().text( "left: " + position.left + ", top: " + position.top );
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -7):

Try:
`$('#mytable').attr('offsetTop')`

Comment: this works, is corss-browser? I can't test in all browsers, only in firefox and IE6+

Comment: everything in jQuery is *supposed* to work in the browsers specified on the home page for jQuery.