# how to know the the objects x and y position in web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the top position of an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101292/how-to-get-the-top-position-of-an-element)

i am just wondering how to know the correct position of an object in the webpage.  I try to solve this doubt myself. But i am not able to solve. In other language like AS3, there is x and y properties are there to know the position. but using java script or j query, i do not know how to do this.

here is little bit of code to start :
i want to know the container object's x and y position.

```
$(function(){
  var myObject = $('#container');
  var objectXpos;
  var objectYpos;
});
```

thanks, naresh kumar.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches you can take, using either `offset()` or `position()`:

```
$(function(){
  var myObject = $('#container'),
      posX = myObject.offset().left,
      posY = myObject.offset().top;
});
```

Or:

```
$(function(){
  var myObject = $('#container'),
      posX = myObject.position().left,
      posY = myObject.position().top;
});
```

The differences are simply that `offset()` returns the coordinates of the element's top-left corner in relation to the *page*, whereas `position()` returns the coordinates relative to its offset-parent element.

References:

- [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).
- [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Comment: ok. both options are working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jQuery you can use:

```
$(function(){
  var myObject = $('#container'),
      offset = myObject.offset(); //then you can access offset.top and offset.left
});
```

Comment: ok, it's working fine. so one method takes care of both position.